# portfolio website - how should i begin

Tags: php, html

I have this plan to create my own portfolio website and it has been bugging me for two months already. the portfolio is like any typical portfolio - intro, services, contact, blog but i plan to make it from scratch with or without a CMS/Framework. i have already planned bunch of how it works in diagrams, pseudo-code scribbles

but how do i start? should i start as a static website and work my way into the JS, PHP and SQL or should i drop the interface for later and do the other way around by doing the back end actions first?

Comment: "i plan to make it from scratch" - why would you like to reinvent the wheel? Frameworks are made to simplify the coding process. Making it from scratch is just a waste of time, isn't it?

Comment: The same way you begin with any of the websites you built so far. With the difference that you have no clients to satisfy, so everything's up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build front to back. Start with the navigation as it tends to be the pivotal area that the site revolves around - most of the personality of the site tends to end up in the header as well.

By starting there, you will find yourself creating an ID/Class convention, and starting to code the foundation of your more intense and interesting scripts.

I've built quite a few sites in my time and I have found this is the most natural progression of things, but of course, everyone is different.

Building the back-end first is an invitation for trouble if you ask me.. start with practice and apply theory rather than starting with theory and trying to realize it.. its like walking up the down escalator!

Answer (score 1):

Build it like any other website. There's nothing wrong with using a framework or CMS platform for your own site. If you're any good, you'll hardly have time to dedicate to your own site so using an off-the-shelf package and then designing the site on top of it may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Both.

If you have designs (photoshop? drawings) you might want to finish them of (basing, slicing, whatever you want to call it) as basic HTML. Now you have a static website (non functional) just for the design)

Another tier for your site is the framework/basics (your own or a ready made) that need to work.

And in the end you pour the design over the framework, sit back and watch the money come in :P